# Parse C# object list into key value pair in JS

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object constituting of column model attributes of a grid. I want to populate a dropdown in the grid, for that I have a object list with ID - Value pair.

The grid model takes the values in the following format:

```
values: { "be": "Belgium", "fr": "France", "uk": "Great-Britain", "nl": "Nederland" }
```

My anonymous object structure is the following:

```
List<Object> valueList = new List<Object>();
var item1 = new { ID = "M", Value = "Male" };
var item2 = new { ID = "F", Value = "Female" };
valueList.Add(item1);
valueList.Add(item2);
```

The array structure after `$.parseJSON` is:

```
    [
Object
ID: "M"
Value: "Male"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
ID: "F"
Value: "Female"
__proto__: Object
]
```

EDIT:

Using this for json converter:

```
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(model);
return json;
```

Where model is a list with other grid attributes and List of values.

How would I construct a JSON formatted data from this, such that I have similar results? Is there an proper way to it? Or would I have to do something similar to splitting and making a string out of it?

Comment: what is a desired output for `valueList` translated into JSON?

Comment: Please add your c# Json Convert code. Do you use JavascriptSerializer/DataContractSerializer/Newtosoft.JSON?

Comment: `values: { "M" : "Male", "F" : "Female" }`

Comment: @Murali refer to the edit.

Comment: @faizanjehangir how are you calling server side function to fetch values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> valueList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
valueList.Add("M", "Male");
valueList.Add("F", "Female");

var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(new { values: valueList });
return json;
```

This will serialize as:

```
{"values":{"M":"Male","F":"Female"}}
```